# OOPS Relationship between Soccer Field and Soccer Player

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, class-design, relationships

I am trying to design a simple Soccer game. To keep things simple, I am having a `SoccerField` to represent the field and a `Player` class to represent an individual.

A `SoccerField` will contain a list of players. A Player would belong to a SoccerField (Even though a player can exist by itself, during a game, a player will be part of a SoccerField). How can I represent this relationship?  i.e. For moving a player, how can I would like to access the SoccerField boundaries as well as get other players in the SoccerField and validate if the cell is unoccupied.

```
// Say the Field is represented as a 2D Matrix
class SoccerField {
    int maxRow;
    int maxCol;
    List<Player> players;

    public SoccerField(int maxRow, int maxCol) {
        this.maxRow = maxRow;
        this.maxCol = maxCol;
        this.players = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public initializePlayers(int xPos, int yPos) {
        Player player = new Player(xPos, yPos);
        this.players.add(player);
    }
}

class Player {
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;

    // How to represent that a player belongs to a SoccerField?
    // Can I have a reference to the SoccerField in a player?
    // SoccerField field; ----> Is this an acceptable design?

    public Player(int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        this.xPosition = xPosition;
        this.yPosition = yPosition;
    }

    public move(int xPos, int yPos) {
        // Validate that xPos and yPos exists within the Soccer Field
        // If I have a reference to "SoccerField", I can validate the following
        // 1. Check if a player moves to a valid cell
        // 2. Check if a player does not occupy an already occupied cell
    }
}

class Solution {
    SoccerField soccerField = new SoccerField(5, 5);
    Player player1 = soccerField.initializePlayer(0, 0);
    Player player2 = soccerField.initializePlayer(1, 1);

    // Now that I have player objects, I want to move the players
    // Imagine a video game where I am taking control of a player and moving the player
    player1.move(0,1);
    player2.move(1,2);
}
```

Any suggestions on how can I better represent the above classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to represent that a player belongs to a SoccerField?
> Can I have a reference to the SoccerField in a player?
> `SoccerField field;` ----> Is this an acceptable design?

Yes, you can have a reference to the (current) `SoccerField` that a player plays on within the `Player` class.

> Any suggestions on how can I better represent the above classes?

That depends very much on the mechanics of the game you are creating.

If the game is intended to be similar to a first-person video game, where one game-player (either human or computer) always controls the same soccer-player throughout the game, then I don't see that much wrong with your current design.

If the game is intended to be played more like a game of chess, where one game-player moves multiple soccer-players around on the field (move the player at (1,1) to (2,1)), then it might make more sense that the `SoccerField` has the knowledge of the position of each `Player` and also the ability to move `Player`s around (with the associated rules checks).

Comment: Thanks! I was intending to design like a game of chess where a single game player has the ability to move multiple soccer players on the field.

Answer (score 2):

Better Create a Game class. This way players exist outside of game also. You can have different kind of soccerfield (like in a PSP game)

```
class Game {
   final SoccerField field;
   final List<Players> players;
   Score teamA, teamB;

   Game(SoccerField, players) { initialize them here }

   movePlayer(player, x, y) { move it here }
}
```

Comment: +1 for an excellent suggestion. This models real life, and removes the need for the circular reference between players and soccer field that others are saying is ok.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative design I like to use in similar cases, is to use *views* or *projections*.

What I mean by this, is to have the `Player` be an interface and have the `SoccerField`, which is already a place where you create the `Player`, create an ad-hoc / anonymous implementation by just projecting the part of the data it already has to implement the player's behavior. Like this:

```java
public interface Player {
   void moveTo(int x, int y);
}

public final class SoccerField {
   // Some internal, possibly optimized data structure

   public Player initializePlayer(int x, int y) {
       // Mark in internal structure
       return (newX, newY) -> {
          // Check whether free, etc.
          // Move
       };
   }
}
```

This is great for cases where the "child" object is really just a part/projection of the parent and it has no real independent behavior. It is less/not suited for cases where the player has behavior on its own, or is polymorphic.

Just as an alternative. YMMV.